# Tracking SonarQube users (asignees) issues evolution

Tags: code-review, sonarqube, code-quality

Is it possible to get some kind of a report of the evolution in time of issues (gross number) assigned to each user of the system? I'd like to track my team members and evaluate them based on wherever they do correct issues or they just pile them up.

If so, how?

Comment: I do not think that there is a simple way of achieving this. Statistics are usually based on *metrics*. And those metrics don't yet contain user specific content. You could try to write your own plugin, that for example populates one metric per user - SonarQube could then render it. But this solution implies, that you do some serious java programming.

Comment: @slartidan sounds like a reasonable approach, we'll have to see what we can do about it

Comment: Make sure to share it to the open source community if it works ;)